# Loop function using urls as input for the filenames

Tags: bash, loops

I have multiple `files` on a another server that needs to be downloaded, processed and deleted following by `script`. The download url is defined as `$FILE` in the script. However, I am not sure how to call the actual filename using `$FILE` in my second command `samtools` since the filename is the last part of the url and therefore not the same as "$FILE". Any suggestions how to define the filename (which is the part after the last / in the url, indicated as * below) so that I can input and output a unique file in the samtools function, and also delete the same file after processing using `rm`.

test.txt

```
gs://hmf-cram-xfdrvdrv/file123535_dedup.realigned.cram.crai 
gs://hmf-cram-dvdvdv/file12353535_dedup.realigned.cram.crai 
gs://hmf-cram-evd/file46475754_dedup.realigned.cram.crai
```

script

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -s 1 -t files < test.txt 
echo "${files[@]}"
for FILE in ${files[@]}; do
        gsutil -u absolute-bison-xxxx cp $FILE gs://bucket_1
        samtools view -@5  -O bam -f 4 *.cram > /home/user/*.unmapped.bam
        rm *.cram
        rm *.crai;
done
```

Comment: Try ${FILE##*/}

Comment: Check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net